# Using measurability of a function to show a measure inequality

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ an $\mathcal{F}$-measurable function. Show that if $\mu(X > 0) > 0$ then there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that $\mu(X \geq \delta) > 0$.

My current thoughts are to show some relationship between $\mu(\{w \in \Omega : X(w) \geq \delta\})$ and $\mu(\{w \in \Omega : X(w) > 0\}$ using some properties of measurable functions, but am not sure how to proceed. Any hints or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need anything from the fact that X is measurable beyond the fact that these sets $\{X\geq{\delta}\}$ will be measurable. Just use the fact that $$\bigcup_{n}\{X\geq{1/n}\}=\{X>0\}$$ and argue by contradiction using measure continuity from below.

Comment: Great minds think alike ;)  +1 for you

Comment: Thank you! First answer ever so I appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, so this gives us $\mu(X > 0) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \mu(X \geq 1/n)$. How does this necessarily give a contradiction? Is the argument that for a sufficiently large $n$ we have the inequality?

Comment: @zerxee It doesn't give a contradiction on its own, but it would give a contradiction if what you are trying to prove were false.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $\{X>0\} = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\{X\geq1/n\}$.

Can all of the sets in the union have measure zero if the set on the left does not?